# What are the original paper(s)/reference(s) using lateral inhibition to explain simultaneous contrast?

Tags: perception, reference-request

I've seen a lot of textbooks and papers explain how lateral inhibition can account for simultaneous lightness contrast, but what is the original theory/papers that I could cite?

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2147566/

Comment: E. Mach
Über die Wirkung der räumlichen Vertheilung des Lichtreizes auf die Netzhaut
Siztungsberichte der kaiserlichen Akademie der Wissenschaften in Wien. Mathematisch-naturwissenschaftliche Classe, 52 (1865), pp. 302–322

Comment: E. Hering
Zur Lehre vom Lichtsinne. V. Grundzüge einer Theorie des Lichtsinnes
Sitzungsberichte der Kaiserlichen Akademie der Wissenschaften inWien. Mathematisch-naturwissenschaftliche Classe. Abth. III, 69 (1874), pp. 179–217

Comment: S.W. Kuffler
Discharge patterns an functional organization of mammalian retina
Journal of Neurophysiology, 16 (1953), pp. 37–68

Comment: the previous three were gleaned from http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698904002482

Comment: H.B. Barlow
Possible principles underlying the transformation of sensory messages
W.A. Rosenblith (Ed.), Sensory communication, MIT Press, Cambridge (1961), pp. 217–234

Comment: im only commenting because i don't know the literature well enough.  you will have to check those to verify.

Comment: If you've read a lot of stuff then cite some of it to place your question in the proper context.

Comment: Voted to close, as libraries can be filled on the topic

Comment: @Christiaan Isn't the OP just asking for the 'initial' one? That isn't 'too broad' if you ask me.

Comment: @StevenJeuris - This question basically necessitates a literature review on when it first appeared in the literature - dig up a recent one and follow the citations back into the dark ages of early electrophysiology. If OP had provided an early paper and then explains that it apparently builds on pre-existing knowledge, but that OP can't trace it back to its origins, it would be fine. As of now, it lacks research effort. I said too broad, but basically it should read - too much work. Call it a homework question or whatever, but it is no good as it lacks any effort on OP's behalf.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks initial research on the topic being asked.